# Best dewormer for puppies

Tags: dogs, vaccination

I have been given Bravecto triworm by my vet for my puppy during vaccinations. Both times that I have given it to my puppy has led to him vomiting after 3-5 hours. He is just 4 months old now.

I have since been told by a friend to try Milbemax. I am a bit sceptical to try anything I am not sure about.

Has anyone had similar problems with Bravecto triworm. Is Milbemax recommended? Or is there better dewormers out there.

Thanks

Comment: where do you live,what is best in one area can be useless in another area.

Comment: Sub tropical climate. Johannesburg South Africa. Milbemax seems quite popular because of spirocerca lupi